# Need a fixed footer at the bottom of the page but position:fixed messes up tab ordering for accessibility

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a paginated form which has a fixed navigation footer at the bottom of the page which we want to remain fixed even if the page has a scroll. This footer must also appear at the bottom of the page for mobile devices / tablets, etc.

I was able to achieve this by using `position: fixed` on the footer element.

I am now trying to text keyboard / tab navigation accessibility on this form and I discovered that because of this, after clicking each next button and then pressing `tab`, instead of focus shifting to the next focusable element on the page, it is going off to the browser (going through the tabs on the browser, bookmarks, etc.).

By removing the `position: fixed`, the footer flies off the bottom but the tab navigation works like a charm.

I put together a sandbox showing the gist of what I am doing.

https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-lumiere-05y7o7?file=/src/styles.css

Is there any way that I can enforce the tab navigation to then move to the next focusable element on the page after a Next page click or do something to keep the footer at the bottom without having to use `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`?

```js
const Page1Component = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Page 1</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Textbox 1" />
    </div>
  );
};

const Page2Component = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Page 2</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Textbox 2" />
    </div>
  );
};

const Page3Component = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Page 3</h1>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
  );
};

const PaginatedForm = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);
  const renderPage = () => {
    if (page === 1) return <Page1Component />;
    if (page === 2) return <Page2Component />;
    if (page === 3) return <Page3Component />;
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <header>My Header</header>
      <div className="wrapper">{renderPage()}</div>
      <footer>
        <button onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}>Next page</button>
      </footer>
    </main>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
    <PaginatedForm />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: goldenrod;
  height: calc(100vh - 30px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  background-color: firebrick;
  height: 30px;

  position: fixed; /* Removing these last three styles fixes the tabbing issue*/
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is not really about react but only the rendered HTML and CSS; perhaps you can reduce to that here?

Comment: This may also be of help to you https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support

Comment: Thanks @MarkSchultheiss I edited the snippet to make it working in the Stack Snippets but using React.

Comment: I removed the 3 lines but still have [what you describe as] 'the tabbing issue'. Can you check your snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I've checked but the issue is not coming from react is just a css issue. I've fixed by using `display: grid` to `main` tag this way we can create a 3 rows table: first element is the `header` with row height `auto` this way only takes the needed space, second element is content and has `1fr` so it takes all remaining space and for footer again using `auto` so only takes the height needed. To make sure the footer is always at the bottom I've set that `main` has a `min-height: 100vh` so it takes the entire height of the screen. This is the final css:

```
main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

header {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 30px;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;

  background-color: firebrick;
  height: 30px;
}
```

Not sure if changes I did on codesandbox are saved: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-cdn-vtxkec?file=/src/styles.css

If your app has different routes the best you can do is to create a new component and use it as layout so content is always inside main.